# Android-x86 VM does not respond to ping

Tags: routing, static-ip, static-routes, android-x86

I have two VMs in VirtualBox, one Ubuntu 16.04 and one Android-x86 32-bit. I have set both of them to be on the same internal network.

In the Android VM, I ran the following (using Alt-F1):

```
android:~ # ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

I can see the IP address being set in `ifconfig`, and the interface is "UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST". Moreover:

```
android:/ # ip route get 192.168.1.2
192.168.1.2 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.1  cache
```

This does not work:

```
android:/ # ping 192.168.1.2
connect: Network is unreachable
```

But this does:

```
android:/ # ping -I eth0 192.168.1.2
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) from 192.168.1.1 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: ...
...
```

I never could manage a ping from the Ubuntu VM (192.168.1.2). It just 
doesn't print anything and says 100% packet loss on termination.

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit**: I realise that if I use the Terminal Emulator from inside Android itself, as a normal user the command `ip route get 192.168.1.2` returns `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`.